# How to programmatically fill a Textbox and then click a button in another application

Tags: java, button, click, window

I want to write a program in Java to access another application's window to do some jobs automatically. Exactly, I want my program automatically click a special menu in that program and after opening a window (which has three textbox and two button), fill out two or three textboxes and then click Add button. I want to enter a long list of information automatically to this program.

Comment: In another program? This means talking to the operating system directly which Java is notoriously not well suited for. Use a programming language supported by the operating system vendor.

Comment: I agree with @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen as there are much better OS-specific tools for this type of job such as AutoIt for Windows.